# CSS selector to add 'before' content where it is NOT the first selector

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I am trying to amend some CSS which basically will only run when it IS NOT the first of its type using CSS - the following works but is showing for all selectors?

```
.networks-body.all .facebook.interaction-container::before
{
  content: "\f09a";
  margin-right: 2px;
}
```

Comment: I think you're looking for `:not(:first-child)`

Answer (score 3):

try to chain `:not(:first-of-type)` before the pseudoclass `::before`

```
.facebook.interaction-container:not(:first-of-type)::before {
    ...    
}
```

Comment: Also check this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717480/css-selector-for-first-element-with-class

Comment: yes, yes, indeed `:first-of-type` is tied to the element, regardless of the class, as explained in several answers on SO, but in this context that class is the only information available I know to target the element.

Comment: yeah ofc. It was just meant as addition. Author didn´t give too much information actually

Answer (score 0):

Edit: fcalderan's answer is cleaner ;)

You can add the prepend to ALL the element, and than remove it from the first of type:

```
.networks-body.all .facebook.interaction-container::before{
    content: "\f09a";
    margin-right: 2px;
}

.networks-body.all .facebook.interaction-container:first-of-type::before{
   content: none;
}
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/mfge1or3/

Answer (score 0):

You could use `nth-of-type(1n+1)` here while still including `::before` at the end.

Inside the brackets, `1n`, means to select every instance, while `+2` means to start at the second instance. In other words, select all instances *except* the first.

```
.facebook.interaction-container:nth-of-type(1n+2)::before {
  content: "\f09a";
  margin-right: 2px;
}
```

**Example**:

```css
li:nth-of-type(1n+2)::before {
  content: 'A';
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
</ul>
```